# mysql get difference from the result of 2 fields queried

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, difference

I'm not good at sql but I can create,understand common SQL queries. While scouring the net it seems its hard to find a befitting way on this query.

I have a query which is

```
SELECT COUNT(`BetID`),
       FORMAT(SUM(`BetAmount`),0),
       FORMAT(SUM(`Payout`),0),
       ROUND((SUM(`BetAmount`) / COUNT(`BetID`)),2),
       ROUND((((SUM(`BetAmount`) + SUM(`Payout`)) / SUM(`Payout`)) * 100),2)
FROM `betdb`
```

I would like to subtract the result of

```
FORMAT(SUM(`BetAmount`),0)
```

and

```
FORMAT(SUM(`Payout`),0)
```

Any other ideas to execute subtraction in this mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the numbers rounded *before* subtracting them (which seems to be the case when you want to subtract the formatted numbers), you'll need to round them first to the same precision as the formatting, subtract and lastly format the result;

```
SELECT COUNT(`BetID`),
       FORMAT(SUM(`BetAmount`),0),
       FORMAT(SUM(`Payout`),0),
       FORMAT(ROUND(SUM(`BetAmount`),0) - ROUND(SUM(`Payout`),0),0) diff,
       ROUND((SUM(`BetAmount`) / COUNT(`BetID`)),2),
       ROUND((((SUM(`BetAmount`) + SUM(`Payout`)) / SUM(`Payout`)) * 100),2)
FROM `betdb`
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e64f/1).

Comment: Oh I see, Rounding numbers before subtracting is also OK. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Use `FORMAT((SUM(BetAmount) - SUM(Payout)),0)`

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`BetID`),
       FORMAT(SUM(`BetAmount`),0),
       FORMAT(SUM(`Payout`),0),
       FORMAT((SUM(`BetAmount`) - SUM(`Payout`)),0), 
       ROUND((SUM(`BetAmount`) / COUNT(`BetID`)),2),
       ROUND((((SUM(`BetAmount`) + SUM(`Payout`)) / SUM(`Payout`)) * 100),2)
FROM `betdb`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a join statement so that the calculation is only done once:

```
SELECT *,t.BetTotal - t.PayoutTotal as Difference 
FROM (
    SELECT 
       COUNT(`BetID`) AS Count,
       FORMAT(SUM(`BetAmount`),0) as BetTotal,
       FORMAT(SUM(`Payout`),0) as PayoutTotal,
       ROUND((SUM(`BetAmount`) / COUNT(`BetID`)),2),
       ROUND((((SUM(`BetAmount`) + SUM(`Payout`)) / SUM(`Payout`)) * 100),2)
    FROM `betdb`
) as t
```